# R Hadoop mapper error subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to write a basic MapReduce using R (Hadoop Streaming). The following is the Mapper function I have written:

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript

con <- file("stdin",open = "r")

while(length(line <- readLines(con = con,n = 1,warn = FALSE)) > 0 )
{
  line1 <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", line)
  if(is.null(strsplit(line1," ")) == FALSE){
    x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(line1," "))[[1]])
    y <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(line1," "))[[2]])
    x2 <- x*x
    xy <- x*y
    cat(x,"\t",y,"\t",xy,"\t",x2,"\n")   
  }
}

close(con)
```

The input file for this contains two columns as given below:

```
1  15.55511341
2   27.53983952
3   39.7767569
4   47.44065279
5   55.0606804
6   68.57527802
7   77.03639749
8   80.92939421
9   94.4431412
10  106.5353655
```

I tried running this mapper directly on command prompt using the following command:

```
cat ../data/Input.txt | ./mapper.R
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Error in unlist(strsplit(line1, " "))[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
  In addition: Warning message:
  NAs introduced by coercion 
  Execution halted
```

It looks like I am making some basic mistakes in the code. Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: The first line of your input text has 2 whitespaces. The second, 3 and so on. You need to evaluate the number of whitespaces for each line before splitting them with `strsplit`.

Comment: How did you find the whitespaces? In the text file I only see a tab between the two values. Any I tried adding the following two lines to trim the whitespaces: trimWhiteSpace <- function(line) gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", line); line <- trimWhiteSpace(line) I get the same error message: Error in unlist(strsplit(line1, " "))[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Execution halted

Comment: So, it's your example which is not reproducible. And it is better to strip tabulation using `'\t'`.

Comment: Surprisingly it doesn't work with '\t'...it only works with ' '...not sure why...BTW I figured out the error...please see my comment in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues in the `regex` that you are using in your `gsub`.
Try the following piece of code.

```
con <- file('stdin',open = 'r')
while(length(line <- readLines(con = con,n = 1,warn = FALSE)) > 0 )
    {
        line1 <- gsub('\\s+', ' ', line)
        line1 <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", '', line1)
        res <- unlist(strsplit(line1,' '))
        if(length(res)==2){
            x <- as.numeric(res[1])
            y <- as.numeric(res[2])
            x2 <- x*x
            xy <- x*y
            cat(x,"\t",y,"\t",xy,"\t",x2,"\n")
        }
    }

close(con)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This runs the code fine for the 10 lines and produces the correct output but at the end throws the following error: Error in unlist(strsplit(line1, " "))[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Execution halted

Comment: can your please provide the data for which it is showing this error

Comment: I have a txt file that contains two tab separated columns (as shown in the original post). It contains the same 10 rows given in the original post.

Comment: I have edited my answer a little bit. Please give it a shot. The data in the question is not really tsv. as @pascal mentioned

Comment: Figured out what the error is...there was an empty line after the 10th line and the code ran without errors after fixing it...looks like the error is coming from strsplit command...am surprised if condition didn't capture...unless the error is from the gsub command